# Python program to calculate an expression (equation) from the values of second column

Tags: python, equation

I have values as:

```
0.263 0

0.265 0

0.267 0

0.269 0.0001

0.271 0.0003

0.273 0.0006

0.275 0.0011

0.277 0.0021

0.279 0.0029

0.281 0.0046

0.283 0.0072

0.285 0.0113
```

I want to calculate the expression ie., `PMF(W_r)= k_b T ln g(r)`. Where the `g(r)` are the values of the second column.

Here is the code that i have tried:

```
import numpy as np
#import panda as pd
import scipy.constants as sc
#from astropy import constants as const
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
A=open('rdf_CaOw.dat','r')
B=open('pmf.dat','w')
for column in A:
    c=column.strip().split()
    B.write(column[6:11]+'\n')
B.close()
A.close()

C=open('pmf.dat', 'r')
D=open('pmf1.dat','w')
for line in C:
    W = (- float(sc.Boltzmann * 298 * float (math.log (C))))
    print (W)
```

1) Any suggestions on this?

2) Can I directly take the second column and insert/put in the equation to calculate?

How can I do this? Since here I am writing the second column to one output file and from that output file again I am putting the equation.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can take straight the second column

```
with open('rdf.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        cols = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
        print (cols[1])
```

Output

```
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0001
0.0003
0.0006
0.0011
0.0021
0.0029
0.0046
0.0072
0.0113
```

You can use it now for your further maths.

Comment: @ Richard, Thank you for suggestions. Actually, after the math calculations, i need to plot the same 1st column (in my question) v/s the value i got after this calculation. So, how can i do this without much complication.?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html,these are scatterplots with examples.You must install matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

> 2) Can I directly take the second column and insert/put in the equation to calculate?

Yes, your file (pmf.dat) is acting as a variable and is completely unnecessary.

First off:

```
for column in A:
```

That line iterates the file by lines, so `row` might be a better variable name here. You want the values from second column? Then `row[1]` is what you need.

You can use a for loop:

```
C = []
for row in A:
    C.append(row.split()[1])
```

Or better, you can use list comprehension.

```
C = [row.split()[1] for row in open('rdf_CaOw.dat','r')]
```

Walla! There you have it.

```
C = [0, 0, 0, 0.0001, 0.0003, 0.0006, 0.0011, 0.0021, 0.0029, 0.0046, 0.0072, 0.0113]
```

You seem to be trying to get the last 5 values too.

```
C[-5:] gives [0.0021, 0.0029, 0.0046, 0.0072, 0.0113]
```

I believe this is a better practice compared to `C[6:11]`

Comment: If i give the line as `C=[] for row in A: C.append(row[1]), then i am getting ['.', '.',....]. which is considering the second value which is decimal as .  in 0.263.

Comment: You're indeed correct. I forgot to split() the row first. Just updated my answer! @D.H.N